# htaccess redirect to new domain with parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect from `abc.com/param` to `test.bcd.com/?query=param` via htaccess.

Is it correct?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?test\.bcd\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://test.bcd.com/?query=%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Is it?  Try it out on a test server, if you have a specific issue, post back.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^query=param [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?test\.bcd\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://test.bcd.com%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} [R=301,L]
```

for redirect to index.html then try this

Please add following two lines to allow a specific file to load just in case there is no default index file setup already

```
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

Note : if you have to load first php index file then you have set like

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Comment: Is it possible to fix index.html? Not redirect it to another domain.